# Adding colorful background to equation by acting directly on MathJax without CSS

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, mathjax

I am trying to add a colorful background to an equation. I can accomplish that by using `CSS`, but now I am wondering where it is possible to do that directly in the script calling MathJax.

Please, find below a `rmarkdown` example.

```
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
---

Some text:

$$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_ 1 X_1 + \ldots + \beta_n X_n.$$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy:

```
$$\require{color}\colorbox{magenta}{y = (sin)x}$$
```

[image]

For the coloring text of an equation you can use:

```
$$\color{green}{y = (cos)x}$$
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @manro, but is it possible to have the equation with the _typical_ LaTeX math fonts?

Comment: I have just found out how, @manro: `$$\require{color}\displaystyle{\colorbox{yellow}{$ y = \sin x$}}$$`. Thank you very much indeed for your help!

Comment: @PaulSmith Good luck, you are a lover of the colors at the SO ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes! It is possible to have the LaTeX Math fonts using "\colorbox":

Simply ensure that your Math (or text) code is between a single "$" sign, like this (leave no spaces after or before the single "$" sign!):

```
$$\require{color}\colorbox{yellow}{$y = (sin)x$}$$
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpVRl.png)

**Note:** Under MathJaX **version 3**, you don't need to use "\require{color}".