# textcolor inside bookdown math blocks

Tags: lua, knitr, bookdown, tex

I am trying to get text coloring to work inside tex/math blocks.
The code I inherited in latex is

```tex
\[
H_0: b = \textcolor{orange}{0}
\]
```

This works fine for pdf but not for html. I have then read https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/font-color.html and tried to use the LUA filter. It works fine if I just write `[0]{color="orange"}`.

But if I write it within the math block

```tex
\[
H_0: b = [0]{color="orange"}
\]
```

I get the error:

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.3108 \[H_0: b = [0]{color="orange"}
                                     \]
```

I believe this is because the original code, `[0]{color="orange"}`is kept in the intermediate tex file.

Any idea of how I can make this work in both pdf and html?
For more complicated blocks I have used `exams::tex2image` to get an image I can insert in any format, but that is a bit of an overhead in these small blocks.

Comment: Probably better suited to https://tex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Probably right. Posted there too now: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625509/textcolor-inside-bookdown-math-blocks

Comment: @JanStanstrup Yesterday I answered there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70280283/adding-colorful-background-to-equation-by-acting-directly-on-mathjax-without-css/70280847#70280847

Comment: @manro ahhh. That was ridiculously easy. Changed `textcolor` to `color`. Thanks! 
So with the LUA filter can write `[0]{color="orange"}` as part of the text and `\color{orange}{0}` in math blocks works out of the box.

Comment: @JanStanstrup Thanks for the interesting information too ;)